# How to filter database results to only show those that were created by the currently logged in user?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, json

So, I'm working on a project where I have an HTML list being pulled from JSON data by way of JavaScript. The list is located in the currently logged-in user's profile and displays jobs from JSON data. I already have a working search filter; however, I want this list to only display jobs that the currently logged-in user posted. I understand the concept of how this will work, I'm just unsure of how to apply this in Javascript.

The concept:

1. Get job data from JSON.
2. Get currently logged-in user's ID.
3. Match user's ID to each job's createdByID from JSON data.
4. Display those with matching IDs, hide the jobs that don't.

[LINK TO CODEPEN WITH WORKING EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/DevMatt/pen/vYRvgmy?editors=1010)

Here is the working JavaScript:

```
//USER'S ID NUMBER
var userID = "123456789"

//MATCH THIS WITH THE createdByID NUMBER FROM JSON DATA
//...code here...


//SEARCH FILTER:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jobsSearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#jobsData tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text()
                     .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});


/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function dropdownFilter() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}



$(document).on('click', '.accordionList', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('activeLink')
  $(this).next().toggle(200)
})

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordionList");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("activeLink");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}

$(function() {
  var records = [];
  $.getJSON('https://v1.nocodeapi.com/devmarq/airtable/zUIqzVWzLWAiqEpd?tableName=JobListings&fields=company,role,jobID,createdByID,jobType,experience,jobLocation,roleDescription,qualifications,logo,dateCreated&view=AllListings', function(data) {
    $.each(data.records, function parseJSON(i, { fields: f }) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" +
          "<td style='padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;'>" +
          "<div>" +
          "<a href='jobtest.html?jobID=" + f.jobID + "'>" +
          "<div class='jobListBG' style='border: 1px solid #e2e2e2; border-radius: 15px; padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%; padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%;'>" +
          "<div class='jobListCard1' style='padding-left: 1%'>" +
          "<img src='" + f.logo + "' style='float: left; width: 80px; height: 80px; object-fit:cover; border-radius: 100px;'/>" +
          "<div class='jobListCard2'>" +
          "<span style='font-size: x-large'>" + f.role + "</span>" +
          "<br>" +
          "<span style='color: #2b2b2b;'>" + f.company + "&nbsp;<span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='material-symbols:verified-outline-rounded' style='color: red; font-size: 20px;'></span></span>" +
          "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
          "<span style='color: #2b2b2b;'><span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='ph:users-three' style='color: #474747; font-size: 20px;'></span>&nbsp;901-1000</span>" +
          "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
          "<span style='color: #2b2b2b;'><span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='bx:dollar' style='color: #474747; font-size: 20px;'></span>50k-80k+</span>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<p class='jobListCard2' style='float: right; padding-right: 2%; font-size: medium;'>" + f.dateCreated + "</p>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<div style='padding-left: 11%;''>" +

          "<span style='color: black; font-weight: 700;'><span class='iconify-inline' data-icon='eva:pin-outline' style='color: #000000'></span>&nbsp;" + f.jobLocation + "</span>" +
          "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
          "<span style='color: white; background-color: red; padding-top: 0.6%; padding-bottom: 0.4%; padding-left: 1.5%; padding-right: 1.5%; border-radius: 15px'>" + f.jobType + "</span>" +
          "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
          "<span style='color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: #6188ff; padding-top: 0.6%; padding-bottom: 0.4%; padding-left: 1.5%; padding-right: 1.5%; border-radius: 15px'>" + f.experience + "</span>" +

          "</div>"
      "</div>" +
        "</a>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
    });
  });
});

//make each row of table from database link to jobtest.html and display data dynamically based on which row was clicked
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#userdata tbody tr').click(function() {
    var jobID = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    window.location.href = "jobtest.html?jobID=" + jobID;
  });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Epilogue:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.iconify.design/2/2.2.1/iconify.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <input id="jobsSearch" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search by company, role, location" style="color: black; box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.8); width: 90%; border-radius: 50px; padding: 1.5%; padding-left: 50px; background: url(/img/search.png) no-repeat left; background-position: 15px; background-size: 20px;">
        <table id="userdata" style="width: 100%;">
            <tbody id="jobsData">
                
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Epilogue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Epilogue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color:rgb(37, 37, 37);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a: hover {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tdpadding {
  padding: 10%;
}

.active-red-2 input.form-control[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #ff0000;
}

.jobListCard1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.jobListCard2 {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0.6%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: large;
}
```

I really would like to understand how to get this to work, and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: why do you filter them in client side? better practice is to filter them at server side. if they all delivered to client you have 1. a lot of unnecessary data 2. security problem if one user can access another user data

Answer (score 0):

I think use if condition when creating variable tblRow.

Retrieved createdByID field's type is number not string

```
if(f.createdByID === 123456789){
        
      var tblRow = "<tr>" +
          "<td style='padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;'>" +
             ...
             ...
             ...
          "</tr>"

}
```

In my opinion you should edit or add API request in backend. When you call an json data, you should attach logged in user's ID as a parameter in URL. Then retrieve only logged in user's list. Now it is retrieving whole list.

Comment: How would I do this in the backend? I'm using Airtable as my DB and my site is accessing it through NoCodeAPI.

Comment: I don't know. Airtable requires a user login so can't get access to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Your json data contains an array called 'records' so you can filter them to match the id as follows (where id is the logged in user's id:

```
unfilteredRecords=data.records;
id='rec6LJ0WUy30M4Cys';
filteredRecords=unfilteredRecords.filter(record => record.id==id);
```

Just pop this code after function(data) {... like so

```
function(data) {
    unfilteredRecords=data.records;
id='rec6LJ0WUy30M4Cys';
filteredRecords=unfilteredRecords.filter(record => record.id==id);
    $.each(filteredRecords...
```

Comment: Again, as everyone else is pointing out, it's strongly recommended to do the filtering on the back end and not the browser for both server bandwidth and security reasons.

Comment: How would I do this in the backend? I'm using Airtable as my DB and my site is accessing it through NoCodeAPI.